# Does user have to be logged in to their google accout for Google Cloud Messenger to work on Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

For my Android application to receive the registration ID that I need for Google Cloud Messenger does the user have to be logged into their Google account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre android3.0, yes

> It uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0
>   devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their
>   mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices
>   running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html